# Perform count on similar values in using Pig for multiple line of dataset

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, using, multiline, word-count

I am new in PIG and trying to solve a problem on wordcount (website) for multiple line of input(websites).
For example my input dataset has the value

**Input data**

```
Email     websites
e1        web1 web2 web3 web1 ....
e2        web2 web3 web2 web2 web4 ...
e3        web1 web2 web1 web4 .....
```

and my desired **output** will be

```
Email     websites
e1        web1(2) web2(1) web3(1) ....
e2        web2(3) web3(1) web4(1) ...
e3        web1(2) web2(1) web4(1) .....
```

In my dataset i have almost 50000 email id(user)

Comment: What's the separator between email and websites?

Comment: Please post the Pig script you have written and why you think it's not working.

Comment: email and websites are separated by (;)-Tariq

Comment: Users    = load 'users' using PigStorage(';') as (email:chararray, url1:chararray, url2:chararray,url3:chararray...);  
Grouped = group Users by email;   after these two lines i have no idea what to do next. I tried several code collected from different forum but i didn't get my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming email and websites are tab separated and websites themselves are space separated.  Following is step by step code to get desired output, the main idea is to first tokenize the websites, flatten them, do group by (email, tokenize_website), generate count, then do a group by email.

```
A = LOAD 'sample.txt' AS (email:chararray, urls:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE email AS email, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(urls)) AS tokenize_urls;
```

Dumping B

```
e1  web1
e1  web2
e1  web3
e1  web1
e2  web2
e2  web3
......
```

Now grouping by (email, tokenized urls) and generating count

```
C = GROUP B BY (email, tokenize_urls); 
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group.email as email, group.tokenize_urls as url, 
                COUNT(B) as url_count;
```

Dumping D

```
e1  web1    2
e1  web2    1
e1  web3    1
e2  web2    3
....
```

Now grouping by email

```
   E = GROUP D BY email;
```

Dumping E

```
e1  {(e1,web1,2),(e1,web2,1),(e1,web3,1)}
e2  {(e2,web2,3),(e2,web3,1)}
e3  {(e3,web1,2),(e3,web2,1),(e3,web4,1)}
......
```

PS: I am myself newbie to PIG, so the solution I have may not be optimal.

Comment: This should be the optimal way without writing a UDF (which would be pretty painless in this case).